# MAUI custom control positioning on load

Tags: c#, mobile, maui, app.xaml

I have Frame(with Entry) inside custom control

```
   ` <Frame Grid.Row="0" 
       Grid.Column="1"
       x:Name="entryFrame"
       ...>
    <Entry Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}, Path=ContactText}"
           x:Name="entryContact"
           ...>
        <Entry.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
        </Entry.GestureRecognizers>
    </Entry>
</Frame>`
```

Frame should change position and colour depending on some property.

```
   protected void SetIsAvailable(bool _isavailable)
    {
        if(_isavailable)
        {
            entryFrame.BackgroundColor = Colors.LightSeaGreen;
            entryFrame.TranslateTo(0, 0, 0, easing: Easing.Linear);
        }
        if (!_isavailable)
        {
            entryFrame.BackgroundColor = Colors.PaleVioletRed;
            entryFrame.TranslateTo(100, 0, 0, easing: Easing.Linear);
        }
    }
```

Property:

```
  private bool _isAvailble;
    public bool IsAvailble
    {
        get
        {
            return _isAvailble;
        }
        set 
        {               
            _isAvailble= value;
            SetIsAvailable(value);
        }
    }
```

So when property changes I calling `SetIsAvailable(value);` that moving and painting my frame.
In action it works perfect, but.... on first load if I set property in XAML

```
<controls:ContactPicker 
     IsAvailble="False"
     ControlState="Label"
     Labeltext="Phone:" 
     ContactText="65669437254"/>
```

It changes frame color `entryFrame.BackgroundColor = Colors.PaleVioletRed;`, but not changing frame position  `entryFrame.TranslateTo(100, 0, 0, easing: Easing.Linear);`  0_o

According to debugger line is executed, but it doesn't affect Frame.
I suppose, on initialization compiler first initializes controls - then sets up properties(that calls my method) - and only after setting up controls positions and overwrite my changes

The question is - how to force that piece of..... code works correctly and set position and color after full initialization but before showing it to user. Might be there is some `base` method that calling very last and could be overrided?

Before, I also tried to call `SetIsAvailable` method after `InitializeComponent();` in the main constructor, but apparently, Properties set up after. So the method doesn't make any changes.

Answer (score 0):

So apparently trouble is partly the Custom control(myControl) initialization process, partly `frame` by yourself.

Properties are set up after calling myControl main constructor, so changing myCOntrol design/positions depending on properties in the main constructor is a useless idea.
But overriding the `OnBindingContextChanged` method with my `SetIsAvailable()`  helped.

The next part is positioning. Frame conrol does't want to react on any positioning during initialization.... I guess Frame just wrapping himself around control inside(Entry in my case) and inheriting his position state. But if we wrap Entry or Frame by itself in a Grid and position the Grid, it works correctly.

I ain't 100% sure that my approach is totally correct in terms of "good coding" standards, but it works.... so I ain't gonna touch it:))

Comment: Did you try to put `entryFrame.TranslateTo(100, 0, 0, easing: Easing.Linear);` in the page's construction method? I used a label to test, and this can work when I put it in the page's construction method.

Comment: In addition, the `OnBindingContextChanged` method will be invoked when the page's binding context change every time.

Comment: Just tried `entryFrame.TranslateTo(100, 0, 0, easing: Easing.Linear);` in the control constructor method... no doesn't work 0_o It works for labels and grids, no doubt, but not for Frames.  Also for me is essential to set up the control state depending on the properties, but properties are set up after the constructor method, so I'm fu**ed:))

Comment: Yes, I know 'OnBindingContextChanged ' will be calling every time when binding context changes outside, but not from inside, moreover in my case, I bind text on initialization and after just grabbing it back in DataBase if the text changes, so f*ck it:)  At least for now, don't want to get stuck on this issue for long if I find a better solution in the future I'll fix it. Thank you for your reaction;)

Comment: I tested with the frame again, but it also worked when it is in the constructor method. It's strange. All right, maybe I missed some details, happy coding!

Comment: It's weird 0_o Will play with it after)  Thank you))